# Merging dataframes, based on range

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have been struggling my whole day on merging two datasets. One data set shows me an customer ID, paydate and product_code, the other one tells me the special deals the company made with the customer for a special period.

- customer = customer
- product_code = product_code
- date_from <= Paydate <= date_untill

I tried the following script (python):

```
nef_df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Customer', 'Product_code', 'date_from', 'date_untill']], on=['Customer', 'Product_code'])
```

[example tables in Excell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqNJZ.png)

Comment: Please post your data as *code* and not as *screenshots*. Also, update your question to show the code you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share your dataframe - not image. I hope to test it on my sample code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your example, you'll need to perform an **outer merge**.

1. Import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

2. Create raw data (as an example)

```
customer_1 = ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3']
paydate = ['1-6-2020', '26-11-2020', '7-1-2020', '5-12-2020', '1-3-2020', '16-7-2020', '10-1-2020', '31-12-2020']
product_code = [9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9200, 9200, 9400, 9400]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'customer':customer, 
        'paydate':paydate, 
        'product_code':product_code
    }
)
customer_2 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3', 'A4']
product_code = [9100, 9100, 9100, 9200, 9200, 9400, 9400, 9300]
price = [27, 20, 23, 23, 22, 20, 23, 44]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'customer':customer_2, 
        'product_code':product_code, 
        'price':price
    }
)
```

3. Perform an outer merge

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['customer', 'product_code'])
```

Result table:

[image: Result table]